# Artifactory remote npm repo only caching package.json files and not TGZ files

Tags: npm, artifactory

I have set my default registry to use a remote Artifactory repository using `npm config set registry {registry-url}`, so when I run `npm install` my dependencies are cached in the specified registry.

My issue is that it only seems to be caching package.json files with URLs to the dependency's repo, and not the actual Tarballs. Is there a way to configure it to cache the Tarballs as well?

Answer (score 2):

An Artifactory NPM remote repo pointing to https://registry.npmjs.org should cache .tgz packages in the remote-cache:

[image: TGZ]

When you set up the client make sure you are using the correct URL with the /api/npm part:

http://:8081/artifactory/api/npm/npm-repo/

Also make sure the repository is, in fact, an NPM repository and not a generic type and make sure the remote advanced configuration is using the "store artifacts locally" option.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 

My understanding is that artifactory should cache .tgz packages as well, however when I run npm install it only caches the package.json files in the .npm directory, and it does not create the additional directories with the .tgz packages...

My repository is an NPM repository and "store artifacts locally" is true.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. Have you tried clearing out your local disk NPM cache first?

Comment: I just tried that and it worked! Thank you so much for your help!